# How do you say “It takes a while for my head to stop spinning.” in French?

Tags: traduction

**Context** :

**Person 1**: Are you going on this roller coaster?

**Person 2**: No. My head spins after going on roller coasters. It takes a while for it to return to normal.

**Personne 1** : Tu vas sur ces montagnes russes ?

**Personne 2** : Non. J’ai la tête qui tourne après y être allé.

—-

I first proposed the sentence « Ça prend un moment pour ma tête à retourner à la normale. » But I was told that this is not natural.

I was told the natural way to say it is

## « Ça prend un moment à ma tête de retourner à la normale. »

If this is not true please can you tell me. If this is true then please could you help me understand the following:

I don’t completely understand how this sentence has been formed. I understand **“Ça prend un moment”**  and I understand **“retourner à la normale”**. But I don’t understand **à ma tête de**. I don’t know what grammar rules are being used in **à ma tête de**. What is the function of **à**? I feel like maybe it has something to do with the causative construction.‍♂️ What is the function of **de**?

I am entering the intermediate level of french so please can you provide an explanation as simple as possible. Thank you!

Comment: plus naturellement, j'aurais dit : "j'ai eu la tête qui tourne pendant un bon moment" ou encore "ça m'a donné le tournis pendant un bon moment".

Comment: It is odd that *retrouver l'équilibre* is considered by two participants to be right whereas to find one's balance (retrouver l'équilibre) is not necessarily about no longer feeling dizzy. It saddens me to see such a strong denial mechanism for answers that are clearly idiomatic. Too bad.

Comment: @Lambie It saddens me to see non native speakers believing they are in a position to tell native people what is idiomatic or not in their own language.

Comment: Non-native speakers who know more French than a French person like yourself know English, will come up with a better translation. C'est ça, le b.a. ba de la traduction. So only when a French person's knowledge of English is better than an English person's knowledge of French, will the French person do better. This is a well known fact in professional translation circles.

Comment: @Lambie That's a mistake. The knowledge of a foreign language is not at all a requirement for someone to identify if a sentence written in their own language is idiomatic or not, makes sense or not. The source language is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

*Ça prend un moment à ma tête de retourner à la normale* is not idiomatic French. It is perfectly understandable, but a French person would not say it like that.

Several issues:
1- On the precise issue that bothers you, i.e. why *à* and not *pour*, the person who corrected you was correct. *À* has a lot of functions, here it introduces what could be seen as the subject of the action<sup>1</sup>.
But you are correct in thinking that *ça prend du temps pour* is in some cases possible. *Pour* induces a purpose and is followed by a verb, so we could have:
*Ça prend un moment pour que ma tête retourne à la normale*.

2-  "It takes a while": *temps* is better than *moment* here, *il faut un certain temps/ça prend un certain temps*. Not really unidiomatic, just clumsy in this case<sup>2</sup>.

3- *Retourner à la normale* is a usual phrase, perfectly understandable here, but personally I would not use it in this case. Using *équilibre* seems a better choice here.

Here are two proposals to express what you mean, there could be others.

- Il me faut un certain temps pour que je retrouve mon équilibre.
- Ça prend du temps avant que ma tête retrouve son équilibre.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Maybe we could say it is some sort of passive form.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> If I wanted to express a more substantial amount of time I could use *bon moment*, *bon* could not be used with *temps* in this case.</sup>

Comment: On peut retrouver son équilibre sans avoir été étourdi ou avoir eu la tête qui tourne....

Answer (score -1):

« Ça prend un moment pour ma tête à retourner à la normale. » : incorrect

« Ça prend un moment à ma tête de retourner à la normale. » : incorrect

« Ça prend un moment à ma tête pour retourner à la normale. » : correct grammatically, but not the best idiomatic French.

« Ça prend un moment pour que ma tête retourne à la normale. » correct and idiomatic.

Answer (score -3):

L'expression en anglais to feel dizzy ou to have one's head spin, c'est avoir la tête qui tourne ou bien se sentir étourdi/die en français.

**return to normal** en anglais serait pareil que:  to no longer spin or feel dizzy
ne plus avoir la tête qui tourne

Alors, cela donne:

- Il me faut un moment pour ne plus avoir la tête qui tourne.       L'expression idiomatique, c'est: avoir la tête qui tourne ou se sentir étourdi: to feel or be dizzy or to have one's head spin.
- Il me faut un moment pour ne plus me sentir étourdi/die.

return to normal in English = to no longer be dizzy. I would not use à la normale here in French. It's too literal here.

> **Une astuce facile et rapide pour ne plus avoir la tête qui tourne**
> Sur le réseau social américain Reddit un internaute révèle une
> technique simple utilisée par les pilotes de l'air américains pour
> faire remonter rapidement le sang au cerveau **lors d'un
> étourdissement.** [dizzy spell]

[tête qui tourne _ étourdissment](https://www.medisite.fr/a-la-une-une-astuce-facile-et-rapide-pour-ne-plus-avoir-la-tete-qui-tourne.1105258.2035.html)

Comment: "Avoir la tête qui tourne": oui, c'est ça. "Se sentir étourdi": pas trop. C'est un calque de l'anglais qu'on rencontre beaucoup plus au Québec qu'en France où *étourdi* a le plus souvent une autre signification aujourd'hui : celle qui est liée à l'étourderie et pas à l'étourdissement.

Comment: @jlliagre Par vertige on entend **un étourdissement**, une sensation de perte d'équilibre avec l'impression **soit qu'on a la tête qui tourne, soit que les objets, le mur, le plafond tourne autour de nous**. Dans ce second cas, des nausées, des difficultés à tenir debout et des angoisses peuvent survenir. Petit tour d'horizon. https://sommeil.ooreka.fr/astuce/voir/565163/vertiges-au-reveil = to feel dizzy, to feel like your head is spinning

Comment: **Se sentir étourdi en se levant brusquement** peut être normal, mais certains cas, faites appel à un médecin https://fabiosa.fr/lbpfc-8037-pbmvn-se-sentir-etourdi-en-se-levant-peut-etre-normal-mais-il-faut-dans-certains-cas-faire-appel-a-un-medecin/= to feel dizzy when you stand up too fast. Both texts are French, both mean to feel dizzy or feel like your head is spinning.

Comment: Cela peut juste stresser un peu ou angoisser, donnant l'envie d'hyperventiler, c'est-à-dire d'inspirer trop vite et **donc se sentir étourdi [dizzy] ou affaibli**.  https://www.allodocteurs.fr/maladies-maladies-infectieuses-et-tropicales-coronavirus-info-ou-intox-les-dangers-du-port-du-masque-29907.html//Bon, il me semble que cela suffit comme exemple.

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit que ça ne se rencontrait pas en France, juste que ce n'était pas terrible comme traduction. Et j'ai bien fait la distinction entre étourdissement et étourderie. Ton premier lien ne contient pas l'adjectif étourdi.

Comment: @jlliagre feel dizzy (head spinning) Avoir la tête qui tourne ; Avoir des vertiges ; Se sentir étourdi https://parlezvousanglais.fr/expressions-enfr/feel-dizzy-traduction-francaise/ J'aurai du dire **avoir des vertiges**, aussi.

Comment: C'est dommage de ne jamais tenir compte des remarques de francophones natifs.

Comment: C'est dommage quand les votes négatifs sont si trompeurs..

Comment: to be dizzy or have one's head spin and, to feel normal again is not regain one's balance: retrouver son équilibre. Ça serait une faute de traduction. Les francophones natifs ne sont pas nécessairement des traducteurs....justement, on me donne des votes négatifs parce que je suis anglophone, pas parce que ma réponse n'est pas bonne.

Comment: https://parlezvousanglais.fr/expressions-enfr/feel-dizzy-traduction-francaise/ **feel dizzy**: Avoir la tête qui tourne ; Avoir des vertiges ; **Se sentir étourdi**. Je ne me sens plus étourdi. est parfaitement idiomatique. It takes a while: il me faut un moment

Comment: Il me faut un moment pour réfléchir. https://www.lemoniteur.fr/article/plof.940854 Alors, "il me faut un moment pour ne plus me sentir x" marche très bien. Mais avant le problème de idiomaticité, il y a vocabulaire. dizzy /no longer dizzy=return to normal. La traduction de: return to normal n'est pas retourner à la normale pour une personne qui se sent étourdi.

Comment: *My feel dizzy after touring this city.* C'est une phrase correcte, ça ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134026/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).